# Can you display the name of monsters in general?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a way to get the monsters to display names above their head in-game. I am in Hardcore and it would help to see the names of the enemies well ahead of time.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no such an option. The only thing I would recommend you: memorise the looks of the enemies and know which ones you should avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen on xbox 360 and reading online, only the upper level monsters will (can) have their names above. I think this is mostly due to the fact that when an area is densely populated it will be an absolute jumble of monster names and may affect to your game performance (in contrast to the health bar which only shows once you attack another enemy).